# Cloning dribbble layout. How did I do and what needs to be improved?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am cloning the left picture of this design:

https://dribbble.com/shots/2262761-Mobile-Blog-App-Interface/attachments/424147

Here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/TheKyleDev/project/full/ZWbLbw

Code: https://codepen.io/TheKyleDev/project/editor/ZWbLbw

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <header class="hero">
        <h4>Mark Manson</h4>
        <h1>The<br />Dark Side<br />of the<br />Digital<br />Nomad</h1>

        <div class="btn"><a href="#">Travel</a></div>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <p class="close-btn">Close</p>
        <div class="dots-container">
          <div class="dot"></div>
          <div class="dot"></div>
          <div class="dot active"></div>
          <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
        <p class="chat">Chat</p>
      </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I wanted help on how I can improve this, what is bad about it and how my way of coding it is.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<title>` tag between the head tags.